# Instagram api - Retrofit2 - unable to do POST request

Tags: android, curl, retrofit, retrofit2, instagram-api

I am new to retrofit and I am trying to send a comment to a specific media using retrofit and the Instagram API.
The Instagram API tells me that my request must be:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' 
     -F 'text=This+is+my+comment'
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments
```

and the JSON response is :

```
{
    "meta": 
    {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "data": null
}
```

So I made this retrofit grammar:

---

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v1/media/{media_id}/comments")
Call<Object> postComment(
        @Path("media_id") String mediaId,
        @Field("access_token") String accessToken,
        @Field("text") String text);
```

My Retrofit Service:

---

```
public class RestClient 
{
    public static RetrofitInstagram getRetrofitService() 
    {
       return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.AUTH_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(RetrofitInstagram.class);
    }
}
```

My call (inside an AlertDialog get the text from an EditText) is :

---

```
Call<Object> call = RestClient.getRetrofitService().postComment(data.get(idx).getId(), access_token, titleEditText.getText().toString());
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response)
                        {
                            Log.d("response comment", ""+response.raw());
                            Toast.makeText(activity_instagram_feed_search.this, "Comments sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(activity_instagram_feed_search.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

My problem here is that I am receiving a code 400 error (Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter.).

It's like the api think I am doing a GET request.

I am really confuse, I would appreciate some wisdom :).

Comment: curl -F argument corresponds to multipart/form-data not application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so you probably don't want @FormUrlEncoded

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I updated the retrofit grammar but I am still have the code 400 related to no access_token

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to my question.
So Ben P was wrong and the Curl -F is x-www-form-urlencoded.

I am in sandbox account mode and forgot to add comments scope to my loggin
WebView request.

So my WebView url is now:

```
private final String url = Constants.AUTH_URL
        + "oauth/authorize/?client_id="
        + Constants.CLIENT_ID
        + "&redirect_uri="
        + Constants.REDIRECT_URI
        + "&response_type=token"
        + "&display=touch&scope=public_content+comments";
```